# Why are the list items from a JSON file coming back undefined jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So I have a dog name tool that is working as far as the pop up I'm using a separate [json](/questions/tagged/json) file to get the names populated into the list as list items. Here are the [html](/questions/tagged/html) and [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) that does this:

```
<div class="dnt-container-mobile seasonal-bg-dark">
  <h1 class="mobile-heading">Dog Name Finder</h1>
  <h1 class="wide-heading">
    <!-- <span class="logo teal icon-akc-logo dnt-logo"></span> -->Dog Name Finder</h1>
  <form class="dnt-tool" id="dnt" name="dnt">
    <div class="dnt-overlay">
      <input id="male" name="gender" type="radio" value="Male" />
      <label for="male">Male</label>
      <input data-id="594" id="female" name="gender" type="radio" value="Female" />
      <label for="female">Female</label>
      <input checked="checked" data-id="0" id="all" name="gender" type="radio" value="All" />
      <label for="all">All</label>
      <select>
            <option data-id="0" value="/dog-name-finder/">Select a Category</option>
            <option data-id="0" value="/dog-name-finder/">All</option>
            <option value="/dog-name-finder/baby/">Baby</option>
            <option data-id="602" value="/dog-name-finder/celebrity/">Celebrity</option>
            <option data-id="603" value="/dog-name-finder/cute/">Cute</option>
            <option data-id="598" value="/dog-name-finder/disney/">Disney</option>
            <option data-id="600" value="/dog-name-finder/fancy/">Fancy</option>
            <option data-id="605" value="/dog-name-finder/most-popular/">Most Popular</option>
            <option data-id="599" value="/dog-name-finder/presidential/">Presidential</option>
            <option data-id="597" value="/dog-name-finder/techy/">Techy</option>
            <option data-id="596" value="/dog-name-finder/television/">Television</option>
            <option data-id="606" value="/dog-name-finder/trendy/">Trendy</option>
            <option data-id="595" value="/dog-name-finder/unisex/">Unisex</option>
            <option data-id="604" value="/dog-name-finder/video-game/">Video Game</option> 
      </select>
    </div>
    <!-- end of dnt-overlay -->
    <div class="dnt-btn">
      <button id="submit" type="submit">Show Names</button>
    </div>
    <!-- end of dnt btn -->
  </form>
  <!-- end of dnt-tool -->
</div>
<!-- end of dnt-container-mobile -->
```

Here is the [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/0.9.9/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#dnt').submit(function(e) {
          var cat_id = $('.dnt-overlay > select > option:selected').data('id') || 0;
          var cat_title = $('.dnt-overlay > select > option:selected').text() || 'All';
          if (cat_id === 0) {
            cat_title = 'All';
          }
          var dnt_url = $('.dnt-overlay > select > option:selected').val() || '/dog-name-finder/';
          var gender = $('.dnt-overlay > [name=gender]:checked').data('id') || 0;
          var gender_title = $('.dnt-overlay > [name=gender]:checked').val() || 'All';
          var title = cat_title;
          var html = '';

          var params = '';

          if (window.innerWidth <= 320) {
            params = '?limit=18';
          } else {
            params = '?limit=21';
          }


          if (cat_id > 0) {
            params += '&' + 'cat_id=' + cat_id;
          }

          if (gender > 0 && cat_title != 'Gender Agnostic' && cat_title != 'Unisex' && cat_title != 'Male' && cat_title != 'Female') {
            title += ' ' + gender_title;
            params += '&' + 'gender=' + gender;
            if (cat_title == 'All') {
              dnt_url += gender_title.toLowerCase() + '/';
            } else {
              dnt_url += '?gender=' + gender_title.charAt(0).toLowerCase();
            }
          }

          title += ' Dog Names';

          $('#dnt-popup > h1').text(title);
          $('#dnt-popup > .more-btn').find('a').attr('href', dnt_url);



          e.preventDefault(); // We don't need to send the form, because it's all local
          if ($('#male').is(':checked')) { // Check if male is checked
            $('#dnt-popup').removeClass('dnt-all').removeClass('dnt-female').addClass('dnt-male');
          } else if ($('#female').is(':checked')) { // Check if female is checked 
            $('#dnt-popup').removeClass('dnt-all').removeClass('dnt-male').addClass('dnt-female');
          } else if ($('#all').is(':checked')) { // Check if all is checked
            $('#dnt-popup').removeClass('dnt-female').removeClass('dnt-male').addClass('dnt-all');
          }
          $.ajax({
              type: 'GET',
              dataType: "json",
              url: "/wp-content/themes/akc/dnt.json" + params,
            })

            .done(function(data) {

              $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                html += '<li>' + value.title + '</li>';
              });

              $('#dnt-popup > .results-list > ul').html(html);

              $.magnificPopup.open({ // open pop up for male
                items: {
                  src: '#dnt-popup',
                  type: 'inline'

                }, //item
                mainClass: 'animated slideInRight'
              }); ///popup open


            });



        }); ///submit function 



        $('#dnt-popup > .more-btn > .long-btn > a, #dnt-popup > .more-btn > .short-btn > a').on("click", function() {

          var cat_id = $('.dnt-overlay > select > option:selected').data('id') || 0;
          var cat_title = $('.dnt-overlay > select > option:selected').text() || 'All';
          if (cat_id === 0) {
            cat_title = 'All';
          }

          var gender_title = $('.dnt-overlay > [name=gender]:checked').val() || 'All';



        }); ///submit function
</script>
```

Here is some of the data in the [json](/questions/tagged/json) file:

```
[{
    "Name": "Aaliyah",
    "Female": 594,
    "Baby": 601
  },
  {
    "Name": "Abby",
    "Female": 594
  },
  {
    "Name": "Abe",
    "Male": 593,
    "Video Games": 604
  }
]
```

Any reason the data would come back undefined? the [json](/questions/tagged/json) is formatted correctly. There's no console error messages.

Comment: where is title in JSON when you are doing `value.title`

Comment: What specifically is undefined? The only async request I see is the request to `/wp-content/themes/akc/dnt.json`, if the data that's in the file is what you show it's not clear why you'd try to access a `title` property, as none is present.

Comment: Ahhh I see. So how would I access the names then since there isn't a title property? @DaveNewton

Comment: @MikeL5799 check my answer :)

Comment: @MikeL5799 Access the properties that actually exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no key as `title` in your JSON. You have to use `value.Name` to acces names

```js
var data = [{
    "Name": "Aaliyah",
    "Female": 594,
    "Baby": 601
  },
  {
    "Name": "Abby",
    "Female": 594
  },
  {
    "Name": "Abe",
    "Male": 593,
    "Video Games": 604
  }
];

$.each(data, function(index, value) {
 console.log(value.Name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to limit the names to 21(asked in comment) then you can do it like this

```
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
 if(index==21){
  return false;
 }
 console.log(value.Name);
});
```

Comment: Oh wow thanks so much. Do you how to limit it to display only 21 names?

Comment: @MikeL5799 Count? Also, note that if you want to display all the properties,  you'll need to iterate over the object keys. Also note that if you want to access the "Video Games" property you'll need to use array notation, not the direct property access syntactic sugar. It might be worth taking a step back and learning some JS basics, though.

Comment: You can limit simply by putting a condition in loop like this `if(index==21){
return false;
}` before appending it to HTML. Remember if you are writing it after appending then check should be for 20 as index starts from 0